# How to read from keyboard without key released method?

Tags: java, keyboard

I am supposed to re-write that code below without using the key released method so that it will have exactly the same result.

The problems I am struggling with is how to make replicate the result when a user holds the same key for longer. With key released method holding the same key for say 2 second will result in only one key being read. With key typed or key pressed methods, the same behaviour will lead to multiple keys of the same type being read.

Would be grateful for the suggestions!

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;    
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 

public class KeyTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    private int counter = 0;
    private String userInput = "";
    private final String secret = "secret";

    public KeyTest() {
        super("KeyListener Test");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        addKeyListener(this);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(counter < secret.length())
            checkSecret(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {
    }

    private void checkSecret(char c) {
        if(c == secret.charAt(counter)) {
            counter++;
            userInput = userInput+c;
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
            userInput = "";
        }

        if(userInput.equals(secret))
            setTitle("Secret password");
    }
}
```